# What static analysis tool can be use to catch error on conditional flow?

Tags: static, analysis, klocwork

I have been checking for some static analysis tool in wikipedia.
I am checking each tool for its capability.

*-Automatic variable checking

-Bounds checking for array overruns

-Classes checking

etc.*

I am really not sure what capability is below:

Be able to check that the variable used in conditional statement is correctly assigned so that it either enters or ignore the statement.

**Example1:**

`bool flag = false;`

`if( flag == true){`

`process1();`

`}`

*The tool should point out that line 2 is incorrect because it will always be false.*

**Example2:**

`bool flag = false;`

`flag = updateFlag();`

`if( flag == true){`

`process1();`

`}`

*The tool should not point out anything since the variable may change before it will be used as condition.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the klockwork tool, which will tell you that code is not reachable i.e dead code.

see the fallowing checkers you can enable in klockwork.

https://docs.roguewave.com/en/klocwork/2016/candccheckerreference

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that klocwork is what we used already. It does not detect that kind of abnormality in codes.